# Testing for a value inside a multi-level array

Tags: postman

I am converting a test from ReadyAPI to Postman and am struggling with this scenario (and I am very new and inexperienced). There is a multi-level array returned from the json (sample snippet below). The ReadyAPI test was very simple in that it checked for the existence of specific value. Specifically, examining the XML, is this:

```
<assertionOfType="JsonPath Existence Match", name="Check for existence of [ilm]"
```

My question is how do I do that in Postman.

*Sample json returned:*

```
"t712714"" {
   "ilm": {
       "hadr": {
           "clusterName": "t712714",
           "clusterType": "hadr",
           "dataCenter": "ilm",
           "extractedTs": "07/09/2022 12:15:07 AM UTC",
           "bindState": false,
           "lockState": true,
           "databaseCount": 29,
           "insertionAgeMins": 4,
           "onlineCount": 29,
           "activeServers": ["testudb602l","testudb604l"],
           "inactiveServers": ["testudb603l","testudb605l"],
       "qrep": {
           "clusterName": "t712714",
           "clusterType": "hadr",
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want to verify that response contains a key named `ilm` ?

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 the way the current ReadyAPI test is written, it looks to me like that's all it's doing, so I guess so to satisfy the requirement.

However, I really would like to test for more because the basic structure of the JSON is

`"cluster": {
     "data center": {
          "high availability disaster recovery": { 
                  "clusterName":
                  and so on as shown in the above
`
So ideally I'd like that we have a cluster ID, a data center id, and then the attributes (clusterName, clusterType, etc) for high availability dr and q replication.

Comment: This tests works, but is this the best approach?
`pm.test("Response contains the right properties", function() {
    let respBody = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    pm.expect(respBody.t712714).to.have.property("ilm")
})`

Comment: Maybe the test is not declarative as the ReadyAPI test but functionally it's equivalent. If you want to more dynamic, just check the key `ilm` existed or not, no matter where the key is, you need write more code.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 yes, that’s exactly what I am thinking to do, but plainly said, I don’t know how to do that and hoping you can give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, testing for a) a 200 response, b) a specific cluster name was returned, and c) ensure cluster name ILM was returned.

```
var resp = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test("Response contains the right properties", function() {
    let respBody = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    pm.expect(respBody.t712714).to.have.property("dfw")
})

pm.test('Ensure data center is returned', function() {
    let dataCenter = "dataCenter";

    _.forEach(resp, (respObj, index) => {
        if (respObj.dataCenter === 'ilm') {
            console.log('Found', respObj);
        }
    });
});
```